# How do I use %s as a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a messages object like below

```
const messages = 
{
  msg1: "the length is less by %s"
  msg2: "the length is greater by %s"
}
```

I want to set it as a variable given a value

```
const value = 6
const check = messages.msg2 % value
console.log(check) // the length is greater by 6
```

Above is how you would do it in python using %. In javascript it gives NaN. How do I do this in javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: That would require me to type out the message when its already stored in an object?

Comment: Then I'd say go with substitution. Of course you can't do that like in python because... js is not python :)

Comment: You can use `+` to attach two strings together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let a = 5;
let b = 10;
console.log(`Fifteen is ${a + b} and not ${2 * a + b}.`);
```

In your case of reusability

```
var message = function(a,b){

    return `Fifteen is ${a + b} and not ${2 * a + b}.`
}

message(10,5) // "Fifteen is 30 and not 40."
```

Comment: Anyway to do this without typing out the message again? Since its already stored in the message object.

Comment: Put the string in the function and call

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? For example in `console.log()` has an second argument

> JavaScript objects with which to replace substitution strings within
> msg. This gives you additional control over the format of the output.

```js
const messages = 
{
  msg1: "the length is less by %s, and this is an %s",
  msg2: "the length is greater by %s"
}

console.log(messages.msg1, 5, "test");
```

Comment: Anyway to set this to a variable?

Comment: @mammywood only way is to use backticks and embedd an variable

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have C style string formatting built in like Python does. You can write a function that emulates it, like this:

```js
const messages = {
  msg1: 'the length is less by %s',
  msg2: 'the length is greater by %s'
};

function formats(string, ...args) {
  const tokens = string.split(/%s/);
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    str = `${str}${tokens[i]}${i < args.length ? args[i] : ''}`;
  }
  return str;
}

const value = 6;
const check = formats(messages.msg2, value);
console.log(check); // the length is greater by 6
```

Answer (score -1):

messages=(value)=>{
return(`the length ${value}`)
}
console.log(messages(6)) //the length 6